# Using Polybase technology in Azure SQL Data Warehouse, can I query data stored in parquet Hadoop formats?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

With the help of Polybase technology in Azure SQL Data Warehouse, would it be possible for me to query data stored in parquet Hadoop formats? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I edited the answer to mention this is now supported.

Answer (score 2):

Today, PolyBase does not support Apache Parquet. It is on the road map to implement within PolyBase as it allows users to take advantage of columnar data structures in Hadoop similar to those in SQL DW. Thanks for the question John - I'll add it to the feature request we're tracking.

Update: Reading and writing Parquet files is [now supported](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sql-data-warehouse-november-2015-updates/).